# How can I prevent merchants from capturing pending Paypal authorizations?

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

We're running a marketplace with merchants that sell services to customers. Payments go directly from the customer to the merchant, and our server facilitates this, through the Authorize & Capture mechanism in Paypal Express Checkout.

In checkout, when the customer's Paypal is authenticated an authorization is created, and at the end of the interaction with the merchant the payment is captured by our server on behalf of the merchant.

There is, however, a back door enabling the merchant to intervene directly on Paypal and to capture the funds in the pending authorization *before* the order is completely delivered. We'd like to prevent that, or at least insert a notice somewhere in the merchant's Paypal account not to capture the payment, and to instead let our server do that for them when the order is delivered. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Normally, you can't do that. But you can read IPN Paypal message to know if transaction are effectives. Take a look to [Paypal IPN Guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/%22IPN%20Paypal%20guide%22), retrieve informations and compare to your informations database transaction to check if all is right.